# How does Titanium dioxide reflect visible and IR lights?

Tags: optics, material-science

I know that titanium dioxide has high reflectance for visible and IR lights, but what is the reason behind this principle?

Answer (score 2):

TiO2 has an extremely high index of refraction. So for a broad range of angles of incidence of a light beam (consisting of a mix of frequencies) onto a TiO2 crystal face, almost all the light will be reflected off it. So if you crush up TiO2 into a powder consisting of many, many tiny crystallites of TiO2 with their crystal facets randomly oriented, almost all the different colors of incident light get reflected (or *scattered*) off the powder in random directions and the powder looks perfectly white.